# Forms button showing in emulator but not showing in the smart device

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

The button inside of my forms is not showing in the device, it only shows in the Visual Studio's emulator. In the device the application loads, the form component shows up, but with nothing inside.

I`ve already tried with other components but nothing seems to work.

Some images of what`s happening:

Emulator:

[image: Emulator]

Visual Studio code and designer:

[image: Visual Studio code and designer]

Motorola MK500:

[image: Motorola MK500]

The code is the standard of a new project, I didn't write anything more, just used the .designer to add the button and that was all.

Comment: I have no experience in Compact Framework whatsoever but in the last image, it seems like part of the form window is not visible. Are you sure this isn't the problem?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes that is what is going on.  The button is there, just off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

On device your window is not displayed whole and button is down.

What i would do is create application in fullscreen with anchoring elements (if it will be run on devices like this).

Other solution (more flexible but could be unnecessary) is to create application that has UI for 2 modes. Normal one and full screen, then on application run check if [some minimum width you want for application to run] < device's screen width => use fullscreen mode || [ some minimum height you want for app to run] < device's screen height => use fullscreen mode else use normal mode

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of issues going on here.  First, your device is a Windows CE device, and you are using a Windows Mobile emulator and a Windows Mobile form-factor in your form.  (You can see the FormFactor property in your screenshot).

Switch to Windows CE, and then set your Form to a size that matches the device you have.  That will help you design for the screen space you have on your device.